# One to one relationship between 2 entities, both are inherited from the same abstract class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, one-to-one

I have 2 Entities which inherit same abstract class.
How to organize one-to-one relationship between that Entities?

```
[Table("AbstractObjects")]
public abstract class AbstractObject{
    public Guid Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public DateTime CreateDate{get;set;}
}

[Table("FolderObjects")]
public class Folder:AbstractObject{
    public virtual Content Content{get;set;}
}

[Table("ContentObjects")]
public class Content:AbstractObject{
    public virtual Folder Folder{get;set;}
}
```

Standard solution works improperly, it makes one-to-many relationship

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Folder>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Content)
                .WithRequiredDependent(c => c.Folder);
```

Comment: Hi there. What have you tired and what was the error message you got?

Comment: Hello, I have no implicit errors, the problem is that, I want to make one-to-one relationship, but it becomes one-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Folder>()
                .HasRequired(x => x.Content)
                .WithRequiredPrincipal(); // <- this is what's different
```

Edit:

The problem is your inheritance implementation - why don't you explain what you're trying to accomplish with your inheritance strategy - my guess is you want the folder/content tuple to contain the exact same data represented by the AbstractObjects entity, but in your implementation the Folder and Content entities will have their own distinct copy of the AbstractObjects data.

If that is the case, you have two options - define Folder and Content to live in the same table and use [table splitting](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/24/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-4-table-splitting.aspx) to define the Folder and Content entities.  Your second option is to use [shared primary keys](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/14/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx) between the entities.

If that is not the case, you want associated Folder and Content entities to have the possibility of having different AbstractObject values; you should remove the table annotation on the AbstractObject entity class definition so that their values are incorporated into the FolderObjects and ContentObjects tables.

Comment: This solution makes 2 foreign keys from Content table to the Folder table. Also I tried to remove the inheritance, and everything works fine, the problem is in inheritance. Why is it so? Who knows?

Comment: I am using inheritance in order to avoid code duplication in my objects, thus all my objects will have all basic properties by default when inherited, I think it will be very useful, in the future. And also, objects dont copy data in own tables, all basic data is stored in AbstractObjects table. Tables of specific objects will store only specific properties.

Comment: I understood the solutions you suggested, as i see they are not suitable for this architecture, table splitting is not because i want to store all objects in different tables, and shared primary key is not possible in this case because when inherited, objects already have unique keys.

Answer (score 0):

After some seaches(googling), I get that I need unique constraint on FolderId field(explicitly created) of Content type, but EF is not supporting unique constraints for fields for now. Thus  the relationship stay on one-to-many. Thanks to all participants!!!